# A href with an "#section" link doesn't jump to section on click

Tags: html, anchor, href

When you click on the items in the menu, the page doesn't jump. Note that when you type it out manually in the address bar, it works fine.

The a `href="#"` links just refuse to work. Is something preventing it?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
    <html style="overflow-x:hidden; width:100%; max-width:100%;">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="description" content="JSA - Joint Schools Activities: a New York City Based Upper School Student Service and Cultural Organization">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">


            <title>Joint Schools Activities - JSA</title>

            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300|Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fascinate|Source+Sans+Pro|Dosis|Abel|Noto+Sans|Droid+Sans|Arvo|Cabin|New+Rocker|Lora|PT+Sans|PT+Sans+Narrow|Arimo|Oleo+Script|Ubuntu|Montserrat+Alternates|Bitter|PT+Serif|Lobster|Shadows+Into+Light|Rokkitt|Libre+Baskerville|Ubuntu+Condensed|Droid+Serif|Open+Sans|Roboto|Oswald|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Roboto+Condensed|Montserrat|Raleway|Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Oxygen|Merriweather|Varela+Round|Francois+One|Roboto+Slab|Titillium+Web|Play|Nunito|Fjalla+One|Inconsolata|Indie+Flower|Pacifico|Hammersmith+One|Righteous|Black+Ops+One|Audiowide|Luckiest+Guy|Lobster+Two|Comfortaa|Orbitron|Carme|Allerta+Stencil|Keania+One|Alike|Rye|Sancreek|Megrim|Fruktur' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


            <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/glide.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/bootstrapoverride.full.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/hovergallery.full.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <link href="css/First_page.style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body style="overflow-x:hidden; width:100%; max-width:100%; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">


            <div class="lg-panelthindark"></div>
                <section class="lg-fullheight">
                    <div id="topoffold" class="graphicpanel fullscreen-cont lg-paneldark ab-light" data-ab-yaq="163.268">

                        <div class="container darker lg-splashbox titlefadeout lg-spacer-medium">
                            <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                                <h1 class="lg-hero-title">JSA: Joint Schools Activities</h1>
                                <hr class="lg-halfwidth">
                                <h1 class="">An Upper School Student Service and Cultural Organization</h1>
                                <h2 class=""></h2>
                                <h4 class=""><br /></h3>
                                <h4 class=""><a href="http://www.jointschoolsactivities.org/index.html#our-mission" target="_top">Our Mission</a> | <a href="http://www.jointschoolsactivities.org/index.html#wwd">What We Do</a> | <a href="http://www.jointschoolsactivities.org/index.html#calendar">Calendar</a> | <a href="http://www.jointschoolsactivities.org/index.html#events">Schedule</a> | <a href="http://www.jointschoolsactivities.org/index.html#photos">Photos</a> | <a href="http://www.jointschoolsactivities.org/index.html#board">Board</a> | <a href="http://www.jointschoolsactivities.org/index.html#contact">Contact</a></h4>   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="downarrow">
                        <a href="#scrolldown" class="text"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-4x"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div id="scrolldown"></div>
            </section>
            <section class="lg-panellight lg-minhalfscreen">
                <div class="container text-center" id="our-mission">
                    <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                        <div class="col-md-7  lg-scrollleftin lg-scrollfadein">
                            <img class="maxwidthimage" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.singlepage.guru/177/images/620912b0b92e135939eeaa19300b7d19.png" alt="macbook">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <h1 class="">Our Mission</h1>
                            <hr class="lg-halfwidth">
                                <p class="lg-left">We are a community of communities.<br><br>We create opportunities for teenage students from many independent schools in Manhattan and Riverdale to come together for good works and good fun.<br><br>We have a program of community service as well as cultural and social events.&nbsp;<br><br>We are a non-profit organization, created and supported by the parents associations of the member schools, in close cooperation with their teachers.<br>We seek to create warm bonds between students, parents, and schools.&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="lg-panelthindark ">
                <div class="lg-graphicpanelthin lg-parallaxfast">
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="lg-paneldark lg-minhalfscreen">
                <div class="container text-center" id="wwd">
                    <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                        <div class="col-md-7 lg-scrollleftin lg-scrollfadein">
                            <img class="maxwidthimage" src="http://www.imagobrand.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/whatwedo.png" alt="hipster">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <!-- h1 class="">What We Do</h1 -->
                            <!-- hr class="lg-halfwidth" -->
                            <p class="lg-left">Service Projects<br>• Winter Carnival for underprivileged children<br>• Sandwich-making for local food pantry<br>• Comfort kits for families at cardiology unit<br>• Landscaping work at local park<br><br>Cultural Events<br>• Photography exhibit<br>• Poetry reading at B&amp;N<br>• Poetry anthology<br>• Battle of the bands<br></p>
                            <p class="lg-left">Student reps: meet once every other month to brainstorm and plan activities;<br>recruit fellow students to participate in service projects;<br>work together with new friends from many different high schools.<br>Parent reps: assist with logistics and communications.<br>Faculty liaisons: assist with the poetry and photography programs.<br>Parent associations: provide funding for JSA’s student-led work.<br><br>Please note: JSA Upper School is not affiliated with the Middle School JSA.</p>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 </section>
                 <section class="lg-panelthindark">
                     <div class="lg-graphicpanelthin lg-parallaxfast">
                     </div>
                 </section>
                 <section class="lg-panellight ">
                     <div class="container text-center" id="calendar">
                         <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                             <h1 class="lg-hero-title">
                                 <div>Calendar of Upper School Events, 2014-2015</div>
                             </h1>
                             <hr class="halfwidth">
                             <!-- h2 class="">[sub title2]</h2 -->
                                 <p class="text-left">Billiards -- Saturday, October 18, 2014 5-7pm<br>Social gathering for JSA student reps at Eastside Billiards, 163 E 86th St.<br>Service Project – Saturday, November 8, 2014 11:00am-3:00pm<br>Riverside Park Leaf Cleanup at 107th St and Riverside</p>
                                 <p class="text-left">Movie Night -- Friday, January 30, 2015 6-9 pm<br>Film screening for JSA student reps and guests; door proceeds benefit local charity. Location TBD.<br><br>Winter Carnival/Service Saturday<br>-- February 28, 2015 11:00am-4:00pm<br>Annual carnival to entertain a group of school children from the Mercy Center. Each JSA member school sponsors a booth with a game, craft, or any other fun activity. JSA students also complete projects benefiting local charities.&nbsp;<br>Prior charities have included: God’s Love We Deliver, Project Sunshine, Mount Sinai Dept. of Health Education, Teen Crohn’s, City at Peace and Yorkville Common Pantry. Location TBD.</p>
                                 <p class="text-left">Independent Voices -- Friday, April 10, 2015 6:00-7:30pm<br>Annual student poetry reading at Barnes &amp; Noble, 150 East 86th Street. This project also features the publishing of an annual anthology of student poetry, Independent Voices.</p>
                                 <p class="text-left">Independent Visions -- Sunday, April 26, 205 1:00-4:00pm<br>Annual exhibition of student photography. Location TBD.</p>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </section>
                     <section class="lg-paneldark lg-minhalfscreen">
                         <div class="container text-center" id="events">
                             <div class="row lg-spacer-bottom-medium">
                                 <div class="col-md-7  lg-scrollleftin lg-scrollfadein">
                                     <img class="maxwidthimage" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.singlepage.guru/177/images/87290d2252c8f6658697715a852b1e0e.png" alt="macbook">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-5">
                                     <h1 class=""><br>Schedule of Meetings 2014-15</h1>
                                     <hr class="lg-halfwidth">
                                     <p class="lg-left">Student Representatives: Thursdays 4:15 – 5pm<br><br>September 18, 2014: Sacred Heart&nbsp;<br>November 6, 2014: BWL&nbsp;<br>January 15, 2015: Browning<br>April 9, 2015: Spence&nbsp;<br>Thursday May 14, 2015: Joint Meeting; Parents and Students at Chapin<br><br>Parent Representatives: Fridays 8:30 – 9:30am<br><br>September 19, 2014: Sacred Heart<br>November 7, 2014: BWL<br>January 16, 2015: Browning<br>April 10, 2015: Spence<br>Thursday May 14, 2015 4:15pm: Joint Meeting; Parents and Students at Chapin</p>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </section>
                     <section class="lg-panellight">
                         <h1 class="lg-center lg-hero-title lg-padtopsmall">Photos</h1>
                         <div class="slider sliderbigimage" id="photos">
                             <section class="slides">
                                 <article class="slide">
                                     <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/16.JPG');">
                                         <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                     </div>
                                 </article>
                                 <article class="slide">
                                     <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/17.JPG');">
                                         <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                      </div>
                                 </article>
                                 <article class="slide">
                                     <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/18.JPG');">
                                         <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                     </div>
                                 </article>
                                 <article class="slide">
                                     <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/19.JPG');">
                                         <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                     </div>
                                 </article>
                                 <article class="slide">
                                     <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/20.JPG');">
                                         <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                     </div>
                                 </article>                                                            
                                 <article class="slide">
                                     <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/21.JPG');">
                                         <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                     </div>
                                 </article>
                                 <article class="slide">
                                     <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/22.JPG');">
                                         <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                     </div>
                                 </article>                                                                                                                        

                             </section>
                         </div>
                      </section>
                      <section class="lg-panelthindark ">
                          <div class="lg-graphicpanelthin lg-parallaxfast" style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/singlepage.guru/images/tumblr_n6rzueLIQy1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg);">
                          </div>
                      </section>


                      <section class="lg-panelthinlight padbottom1">
                          <hr class="lg-backgroundcolorlight lg-lowerchevrondivider">
                      </section>
                      <section class="lg-panellight">
                          <div class="container-fluid text-center" id="board">
                              <div class="row lg-row2columnpicture">
                                  <div class="col-md-6 maingraphic lg-columnpicturefixed" style="background-image:url('./images/exec_board.jpg');">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-6 lg-columnpicturefixed">
                                      <h1 class="lg-spacer-top-medium">JSA Executive Board</h1>
                                      <hr class="lg-halfwidth">
                                      <p class="text-left lg-loremipsum"><b>President:</b> Annette Scattoni<br><b>Treasurer:</b> Roxana Mehran<br><b>Student Committee Coordinators:</b> Cynthia Barba, Annette Scattoni <br><b>Cultural Coordinators:</b> Laura Washington, Annette Scattoni<br><b>Corresponding Secretary:</b> Sharon Singer </p>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </section>


                      <section id="contact" class="lg-paneldark ">
                          <div class="container text-left" id="contact">
                              <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                                  <form action="#" name="contactform" onsubmit="return UserFormPost(this);" method="post" role="form">
                                      <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="Contact form" class="">
                                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                          <h1 class="lg-hero-title-medium">Contact us</h1>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 lg-overflowfix">
                                          <label class="">Email</label>
                                          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" required="required" placeholder="Your email">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 lg-overflowfix">
                                          <label class="">Message</label>
                                          <textarea name="message" class="form-control input-lg" rows="8" required="required" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 lg-overflowfix">
                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg col-xs-12 col-md-4"><span class="lg-send"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>&nbsp;Send</span><span class="lg-sending"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>&nbsp;Sending</span></button>
                                          <div class="lg-formsent col-xs-12 col-md-4"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Message sent</div>
                                          <div class="lg-formerror col-xs-12 col-md-4 lg-hide"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-warning"></i>&nbsp;Something went wrong - message not sent.</div>
                                      </div>
                                  </form>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                      </section>

        <!-- footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="container text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <!-- Left side -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>


        <!-- javascript -->

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.photoset-grid.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.glide/1.0.6/jquery.glide.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>


        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.22/skrollr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.11/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/lgscroll.js"></script>

        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>        
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the full URL inside the `href=""` attribute. Instead, reference only the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#our-mission" target="_top">Our Mission</a>
```

You can also remove the extra styling inside the body tag. Nothing will hide until the width is 100%;

```
<body style="overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the full url and just add the #part to the a href, it will work.

```
<a href="#our-mission" target="_top">Our Mission</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the file with the code changed to work with your requirement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="overflow-x:hidden; width:100%; max-width:100%;">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="JSA - Joint Schools Activities: a New York City Based Upper School Student Service and Cultural Organization">
    <meta name="author" content="www.pixelkraft.net">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">


    <title>Joint Schools Activities - JSA</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300|Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fascinate|Source+Sans+Pro|Dosis|Abel|Noto+Sans|Droid+Sans|Arvo|Cabin|New+Rocker|Lora|PT+Sans|PT+Sans+Narrow|Arimo|Oleo+Script|Ubuntu|Montserrat+Alternates|Bitter|PT+Serif|Lobster|Shadows+Into+Light|Rokkitt|Libre+Baskerville|Ubuntu+Condensed|Droid+Serif|Open+Sans|Roboto|Oswald|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Roboto+Condensed|Montserrat|Raleway|Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Oxygen|Merriweather|Varela+Round|Francois+One|Roboto+Slab|Titillium+Web|Play|Nunito|Fjalla+One|Inconsolata|Indie+Flower|Pacifico|Hammersmith+One|Righteous|Black+Ops+One|Audiowide|Luckiest+Guy|Lobster+Two|Comfortaa|Orbitron|Carme|Allerta+Stencil|Keania+One|Alike|Rye|Sancreek|Megrim|Fruktur' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/glide.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrapoverride.full.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/hovergallery.full.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/First_page.style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="overflow-x:hidden; width:100%; max-width:100%; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">


    <div class="lg-panelthindark"></div>
    <section class="lg-fullheight">
                                                <div id="topoffold" class="graphicpanel fullscreen-cont lg-paneldark ab-light" data-ab-yaq="163.268">

                                                    <div class="container darker lg-splashbox titlefadeout lg-spacer-medium">
                                                        <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                                                            <h1 class="lg-hero-title">JSA: Joint Schools Activities</h1>
                                                            <hr class="lg-halfwidth">
                                                            <h1 class="">An Upper School Student Service and Cultural Organization</h1>
                                                            <h2 class=""></h2>
                                                            <h4 class=""><br /></h3>
                                                            <h4 class=""><a href="#our-mission" target="_top">Our Mission</a> | <a href="#wwd">What We Do</a> | <a href="#calendar">Calendar</a> | <a href="#events">Schedule</a> | <a href="#photos">Photos</a> | <a href="#board">Board</a> | <a href="#contact">Contact</a></h4>   
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="downarrow">
                                                        <a href="#scrolldown" class="text"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-4x"></i></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </section><section>
                                            <div id="scrolldown"></div>
                                        </section><section class="lg-panellight lg-minhalfscreen">
                                                    <div class="container text-center" id="our-mission">
                                                        <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                                                            <div class="col-md-7  lg-scrollleftin lg-scrollfadein">
                                                                <img class="maxwidthimage" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.singlepage.guru/177/images/620912b0b92e135939eeaa19300b7d19.png" alt="macbook">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                <h1 class="">Our Mission</h1>
                                                                <hr class="lg-halfwidth">
                                                                <p class="lg-left">We are a community of communities.<br><br>We create opportunities for teenage students from many independent schools in Manhattan and Riverdale to come together for good works and good fun.<br><br>We have a program of community service as well as cultural and social events.&nbsp;<br><br>We are a non-profit organization, created and supported by the parents associations of the member schools, in close cooperation with their teachers.<br>We seek to create warm bonds between students, parents, and schools.&nbsp;</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </section><section class="lg-panelthindark ">
                                                    <div class="lg-graphicpanelthin lg-parallaxfast">
                                                    </div>
                                                </section><section class="lg-paneldark lg-minhalfscreen">
                                                    <div class="container text-center" id="wwd">
                                                        <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                                                            <div class="col-md-7 lg-scrollleftin lg-scrollfadein">
                                                                <img class="maxwidthimage" src="http://www.imagobrand.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/whatwedo.png" alt="hipster">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                <!-- h1 class="">What We Do</h1 -->
                                                                <!-- hr class="lg-halfwidth" -->
                                                                <p class="lg-left">Service Projects<br>• Winter Carnival for underprivileged children<br>• Sandwich-making for local food pantry<br>• Comfort kits for families at cardiology unit<br>• Landscaping work at local park<br><br>Cultural Events<br>• Photography exhibit<br>• Poetry reading at B&amp;N<br>• Poetry anthology<br>• Battle of the bands<br></p>
                                                                <p class="lg-left">Student reps: meet once every other month to brainstorm and plan activities;<br>recruit fellow students to participate in service projects;<br>work together with new friends from many different high schools.<br>Parent reps: assist with logistics and communications.<br>Faculty liaisons: assist with the poetry and photography programs.<br>Parent associations: provide funding for JSA’s student-led work.<br><br>Please note: JSA Upper School is not affiliated with the Middle School JSA.</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </section><section class="lg-panelthindark">
                                                    <div class="lg-graphicpanelthin lg-parallaxfast">
                                                    </div>
                                                </section><section class="lg-panellight ">
    <div class="container text-center" id="calendar">
        <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
            <h1 class="lg-hero-title"><div>Calendar of Upper School Events, 2014-2015</div></h1>
            <hr class="halfwidth">
            <!-- h2 class="">[sub title2]</h2 -->
            <p class="text-left">Billiards -- Saturday, October 18, 2014 5-7pm<br>Social gathering for JSA student reps at Eastside Billiards, 163 E 86th St.<br>Service Project – Saturday, November 8, 2014 11:00am-3:00pm<br>Riverside Park Leaf Cleanup at 107th St and Riverside</p>
            <p class="text-left">Movie Night -- Friday, January 30, 2015 6-9 pm<br>Film screening for JSA student reps and guests; door proceeds benefit local charity. Location TBD.<br><br>Winter Carnival/Service Saturday<br>-- February 28, 2015 11:00am-4:00pm<br>Annual carnival to entertain a group of school children from the Mercy Center. Each JSA member school sponsors a booth with a game, craft, or any other fun activity. JSA students also complete projects benefiting local charities.&nbsp;<br>Prior charities have included: God’s Love We Deliver, Project Sunshine, Mount Sinai Dept. of Health Education, Teen Crohn’s, City at Peace and Yorkville Common Pantry. Location TBD.</p>
            <p class="text-left">Independent Voices -- Friday, April 10, 2015 6:00-7:30pm<br>Annual student poetry reading at Barnes &amp; Noble, 150 East 86th Street. This project also features the publishing of an annual anthology of student poetry, Independent Voices.</p>
            <p class="text-left">Independent Visions -- Sunday, April 26, 205 1:00-4:00pm<br>Annual exhibition of student photography. Location TBD.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><section class="lg-paneldark lg-minhalfscreen">
                                                    <div class="container text-center" id="events">
                                                        <div class="row lg-spacer-bottom-medium">
                                                            <div class="col-md-7  lg-scrollleftin lg-scrollfadein">
                                                                <img class="maxwidthimage" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.singlepage.guru/177/images/87290d2252c8f6658697715a852b1e0e.png" alt="macbook">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                                <h1 class=""><br>Schedule of Meetings 2014-15</h1>
                                                                <hr class="lg-halfwidth">
                                                                <p class="lg-left">Student Representatives: Thursdays 4:15 – 5pm<br><br>September 18, 2014: Sacred Heart&nbsp;<br>November 6, 2014: BWL&nbsp;<br>January 15, 2015: Browning<br>April 9, 2015: Spence&nbsp;<br>Thursday May 14, 2015: Joint Meeting; Parents and Students at Chapin<br><br>Parent Representatives: Fridays 8:30 – 9:30am<br><br>September 19, 2014: Sacred Heart<br>November 7, 2014: BWL<br>January 16, 2015: Browning<br>April 10, 2015: Spence<br>Thursday May 14, 2015 4:15pm: Joint Meeting; Parents and Students at Chapin</p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </section><section class="lg-panellight">
                                                    <h1 class="lg-center lg-hero-title lg-padtopsmall">Photos</h1>
                                                    <div class="slider sliderbigimage" id="photos">
                                                        <section class="slides"><article class="slide">
                                                                <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/16.JPG');">
                                                                    <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </article>
                                                            <article class="slide">
                                                                <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/17.JPG');">
                                                                    <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </article>
                                                            <article class="slide">
                                                                <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/18.JPG');">
                                                                    <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </article>
                                                            <article class="slide">
                                                                <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/19.JPG');">
                                                                    <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </article>
                                                            <article class="slide">
                                                                <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/20.JPG');">
                                                                    <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </article>                                                            
                                                            <article class="slide">
                                                                <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/21.JPG');">
                                                                    <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </article>
                                                            <article class="slide">
                                                                <div class="sliderbigimagebackground" style="background-image: url('http://dormfair.com/jsa/2/images/22.JPG');">
                                                                    <h1 class="sliderbigimagetitle">       </h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </article>                                                                                                                        

                                                        </section>
                                                    </div>
                                                </section><section class="lg-panelthindark ">
                                                    <div class="lg-graphicpanelthin lg-parallaxfast" style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/singlepage.guru/images/tumblr_n6rzueLIQy1st5lhmo1_1280.jpg);">
                                                    </div>
                                                </section>


                                                <section class="lg-panelthinlight padbottom1">
                                                    <hr class="lg-backgroundcolorlight lg-lowerchevrondivider">
                                                </section><section class="lg-panellight">
                                                    <div class="container-fluid text-center" id="board">
                                                        <div class="row lg-row2columnpicture">
                                                            <div class="col-md-6 maingraphic lg-columnpicturefixed" style="background-image:url('./images/exec_board.jpg');">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-6 lg-columnpicturefixed">
                                                                <h1 class="lg-spacer-top-medium">JSA Executive Board</h1>
                                                                <hr class="lg-halfwidth">
                                                                <p class="text-left lg-loremipsum"><b>President:</b> Annette Scattoni<br><b>Treasurer:</b> Roxana Mehran<br><b>Student Committee Coordinators:</b> Cynthia Barba, Annette Scattoni <br><b>Cultural Coordinators:</b> Laura Washington, Annette Scattoni<br><b>Corresponding Secretary:</b> Sharon Singer </p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </section>


                                                <section id="contact" class="lg-paneldark ">
                                                    <div class="container text-left" id="contact">
                                                        <div class="row lg-spacer-medium">
                                                            <form action="#" name="contactform" onsubmit="return UserFormPost(this);" method="post" role="form">
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="Contact form" class="">
                                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                                                    <h1 class="lg-hero-title-medium">Contact us</h1>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 lg-overflowfix">
                                                                    <label class="">Email</label>
                                                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg" required="required" placeholder="Your email">
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 lg-overflowfix">
                                                                    <label class="">Message</label>
                                                                    <textarea name="message" class="form-control input-lg" rows="8" required="required" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 lg-overflowfix">
                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg col-xs-12 col-md-4"><span class="lg-send"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>&nbsp;Send</span><span class="lg-sending"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>&nbsp;Sending</span></button>
                                                                    <div class="lg-formsent col-xs-12 col-md-4"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Message sent</div>
                                                                    <div class="lg-formerror col-xs-12 col-md-4 lg-hide"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-warning"></i>&nbsp;Something went wrong - message not sent.</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </form>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </section>

    <!-- footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
<!-- Left side -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    &copy; 2014 Joint Schools Activities. Design by <a href="http://pixelkraft.net">PixelKraft.net</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <!-- javascript -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.photoset-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.glide/1.0.6/jquery.glide.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>


    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.22/skrollr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.11/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/lgscroll.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```